# StateIn Operator only emits the initial value

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-stateflow

when I use the combine operator with the stateIn operator to combine two flows to one state flow in the view model, using clean architecture and MVI pattern I only get the initial value of the stateIn operator.

my code is this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class UserViewModel @Inject constructor(private val userUseCases: UserUseCases) :
    ViewModel() {

val userState = userUseCases.getUser()
        .combine(userUseCases.getPreferencesData()) { user, prefs ->
            UserState(user, prefs)
        }.stateIn(
            viewModelScope,
            SharingStarted.Eagerly,
            UserState(initialUser, initialPrefs)
        ) 

}
```

in both of the view model test class and the main activity the value of userState is the initial value
I've also debugged the app; combine seems to work fine (UserState data class gets populated)
I appreciate any suggestions and solutions

Comment: Are user and prefs immutable? If your `combine` runs correctly whenever they emit new data but it fails to flow down to `stateIn` it would mean `UserState` is equal to current value.

Comment: thanks Pawel, no user and prefs are not immutable, they can be changed by the functions in the view model

Comment: So you have to change your `UserState` to contain an immutable snapshot of data you want to display in your view. Or better yet change your use cases to emit new immutable instances instead.

Comment: considering userUseCases.getUser() and userUseCases.getPreferencesData() are normal flows can you explain how?

Comment: I don't have much to work with because you have not posted any part of UserState or your useCase. But `getUser` and `getPreferencesData` flows should be emitting immutable data classes (where all fields are `val`). To update them you'd need new useCase methods that after execution cause those flows to emit updated data.